# AnySoftKeyboard: How do I reorder/remove the keys from the long-press option? I am using Alternate (no mic) layout

Tags: applications, customization

My ASK keyboard currently looks like this:

[image]

There are two parts to this question:

1. How do I control (easily) what characters show up when I long-press on a key?
2. How do I re-arrange those options?

Language pack: English QWERTY Latin Keyboard

Layout: Alternate (no mic)

Comment: [Looks like you need to play around with xml files](https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard/issues/1581#issuecomment-454597290) followed by compiling it and using the APK generated

Comment: @beeshyams that sounds like a lot of specialized work.. :|

Comment: Yes, unfortunately no settings for it, if that is what you want

Comment: @beeshyams thanks man..  so I found out that I need to edit this file: https://github.com/AnySoftKeyboard/AnySoftKeyboard/blob/master/ime/app/src/main/res/xml/ext_kbd_bottom_row_alt.xml one last thing, do you know of a guide or so that can navigate me through how to make an APK with these changes?

Comment: No and the same thing was asked on GitHub and nobody has a guide

Comment: You need to create a custom keyboard layout. I created a few for my personal use: https://github.com/mirfatif/AnySoftKeyboard

Comment: @IrfanLatif figured as much. All the programming I do (which is not much) is exclusively in Python and trying to build my own APK hasn't been very straightforward so far. Android Studio shows a bunch of errors upon opening the project: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252, unclosed character literal, illegal character: '\u2122', not a statement, and such. No idea what to do.